# TextView does not auto-size despite setting it to uniform

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview

I'm trying to work with TextView's default auto sizing functionality but it doesn't work.  I want my TextViews' texts to decrease in size if they move onto the next line and despite setting `android:autoSizeStepGranularity="15dp"`, I barely see any difference.  The 2 TextViews are on top of an ImageView

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".TopImageFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/click"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:tag="img1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_text_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="15dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/impact"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/meme_image_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="15dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:shadowDx="1.5"
        android:shadowDy="1.3"
        android:shadowRadius="1.6"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/impact"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: You set the height to `wrap_content`. The view height is not bounded so it just grows. If you set it to precise value text size will change.

Comment: @EugenPechanec lol what a dumb mistake.  Thank you very much.  If you post it as a full answer, I'll accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text views have height set to `wrap_content`. They will grow automatically to accommodate all the text before changing text size.

Pick one of these depending on your use case (with your own values, of course):

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="100dp"
```

Comment: Upvoted and accepted!  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: I wouldn't "beg" for upvotes if upvotes weren't used as a way for high ranking users to crush on questions because it didn't go hand to hand with their subjective understanding of what a good question is, as opposed to what Stackoverflow describes a good question.  I ask my questions with the SO guide in another tab and yet I have people shutting them down because they got the privileges.  

Btw.  I asked for an upvote if you thought that it was a well asked question.  So at the end of the day, you upvoted it based on your own merit.